# Finding a missing number in an array that uses a random generator

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make it so the random generator doesn't produce the same number in the array. I also don't know how to find the missing number. I tried the if statement, and it works, but it repeats.

The question problem "find the missing number in an array. The array consists of numbers from 1 to 10 in random sequence. One of the numbers in the array is absent and you must find it. Use one loop. An example {5,6,9,4,1,2,8,3,10} – the result will be: 7

```
import java.util.Random;


public class questionThree
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] numbers = new int [10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numArr = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
      int n = rand.nextInt(10) + 1; 
      numbers[i] = n;

      if (numbers[i] == numArr)
        numArr++;
      else
        System.out.println("The missing num is " +numArr);
    }

    for(int val : numbers)
    {
      System.out.println("The next value is " +
                         val);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: sum it up and then you have your culprit missing. assuming there is no repetition and only one number is missing.

`return 55 - sum`

Answer (score 1):

## Assumption:

- Numbers are unique
- Only one entry is missing
- number ranges from [1, 10] inclusive.

Solution

```
return 55 - Arrays.stream(yourArr).sum();
```

This is with O(n) runtime and O(1) space complexity.

If we break assumptions.

You will need O(N) space to figure out which entries are missing. To hold the marker either you can use `List` or `BitSet` or 2 bytes and manage it by hand. N is here the random number generation width.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no mention on using a temporary data structure.
You can either sort the array and find the missing number, OR use a temporary sorted data structure.

Comment: What do you mean by sort the array? Like an arrayList?

Comment: sorting is not necessary here. it can be done in cheaper computational way.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating two things: the generator algorithm for a problem case and the solution to the problem itself. You shouldn't be interested in how the "random array" is generated at all (unless you want to test your solution). What you certainly shouldn't do is try to write the code that solves the problem in the method that generates the sample array.

If you want a randomly sorted list, `Collections.shuffle` will handle that for you. If you want a list without a single element, just generate a list of all elements 1..n and then remove the randomly selected number (then shuffle). So much for the generator. As for the solution, there are many methods to do it, someone already suggested using the sum, that's a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for this code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class questionThree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = new int [9];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numArr = 1;
        numbers[0] = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {
            int n = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
            numbers[i] = n;
            int x =0;
            while(x<i){
                if(numbers[x] == n){
                    i = i-1;
                    break;
                }
                x++;
            }

        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int val : numbers) {
            sum = sum + val;
            System.out.println("The next value is " +
                    val);

        }
        System.out.println("Missing number is " + (55 - sum));

    }
}
```

Output is -

```
The next value is 6
The next value is 2
The next value is 8
The next value is 1
The next value is 4
The next value is 3
The next value is 9
The next value is 10
The next value is 7
Missing number is 5
```

**I am generating 9 Numbers between(1 to 10) randomly and then printing which number is missing among them.**

Answer (score 0):

**You have two options:**

- The way I did it in the code below: setting the random array without repeating the same number. And then a for loop from 1 to 10 and check if that number exist in the array.
- You know that 1 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55. So if you get the sum of all ints in the array you will have 55 - (the missing number). So now the missing number = 55 - sum.

This is the code I did (first method):

```
import java.util.Random;


public class questionThree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = new int [9];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <9; i++)
        {
            //setting random numbers in array without repeating
            numbers[i] = checkForANumber(rand, numbers, i);

        }

        //print all nums
        for(int val: numbers) System.out.println("The next value is " +
                val);


        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            boolean exist = false;
            for(int val : numbers)
            {
                if(val == i){
                    exist = true;
                }

            }
            if (!exist) System.out.println("The missing number is " + i);
        }


    }

    private static int checkForANumber(Random rand, int[] numbers, int i){
        int n = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

        boolean NumAlreadyExist = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(numbers[j] == n){
                NumAlreadyExist = true;
            }
        }

        if(NumAlreadyExist) return checkForANumber(rand, numbers, i);
        else return n;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The next value is 9
The next value is 3
The next value is 8
The next value is 6
The next value is 7
The next value is 10
The next value is 4
The next value is 2
The next value is 1
The missing number is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5];
let sorrtedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
function findMissingNumber(sorrtedArray) {
  let missingnumber;
  for (let i = 1; i <= sorrtedArray.length; i++) {
    let index = sorrtedArray[i];
    if (index + 1 != sorrtedArray[i + 1]) {
      missingnumber = array[i] + 1;
      return missingnumber;
    }
  }
}
let missingNumber = findMissingNumber(sorrtedArray);
array.push(missingNumber);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: The question is tagged "java". Your code is JavaScript. JavaScript and Java are two different languages so I'm not sure how much your code will help the OP. If you look at the other answers you will see that they have explanations as well as code. Perhaps you should consider adding explanations of how your code works?